# Google Glass: How to Launch Contact Application on Google Glass

Tags: android, google-glass

I am trying to launch Contact Application on Google Glass by:

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);

It gives ActivityNotFoundException.

How to launch Contact Application on Google Glass

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS` is not among the [available GDK permissions](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/permissions). This, and the fact that the Contacts Provider is not available on GDK, is the reason for your exception.

If you see this as a need, please file a feature request on the [Google Glass Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list).

Comment: I just need to show any kind of Contact in my app.
Any Workaround that is possible?